# What's the difference between attr.asdict(x) and x.__dict__?

Tags: python, python-attrs

In Python, when you want a dict of the attributes of your [attrs](https://www.attrs.org/)-enhanced class, what's the difference between using `__dict__` and `attr.asdict()`? Which one should you use? For example, in this example they have the same result:

```py
import attr

@attr.s(auto_attribs=True)
class MyClass:
  x: str

value = MyClass(x="hello")
print(value.__dict__)
# {'x': 'hello'}
print(attr.asdict(value))
# {'x': 'hello'}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__dict__` is an implementation attribute that only stores per-instance "direct" attributes (so properties or other computed attributes won't be found there). And it only exists for dict-based types - slots-based one don't have a dict at all.

`attrs.asdict` OTHO uses the type's metadata to get the list of attributes names (so it will work on slot-based classes), uses `getattr()` to get the values (so it will correctly retrieve computed attributes), can recurse on attributes that are "attrs-enabled", etc. But it will, of course, only work on attrs-enabled types...